# how to deploy NodeJs on Windows Azure Cloud Service using command line tools in Mac

Tags: node.js, azure

I am using Mac to try to deploy NodeJs on Windows Azure Cloud Azure, but the official documents are about NodeJs under Windows, I created a new Cloud Service, but it needed me to upload `.cscfg` and `.cspkg`, I searched documents and Google but found nothing useful. And what I want to know is how to write .cscfg and .cspkg file.

Could you give me some documents or articles, or point me a direction to solve this problem?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cspkg file is the "package" that need to be compiled for uploading to Windows Azure PaaS Cloud Services. Unfortunately, this package can only be created via the cspack command line tool (part of the Windows Azure SDK) for Windows OS (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg432988.aspx). You can also learn more about the format of the package file at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj151522.aspx

The cscfg is a configuration file (just a specially names XML file) who's schema can be found at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee758710.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have a specific need for Cloud Services, you can deploy a node application to Azure Web Sites.

There is a [lab](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/nodejs/tutorials/create-a-website-%28mac%29/) for this available. I have actually worked with this functionality for quite a while. You will find the deployment times to be *significantly* faster than with Cloud Services. Much more in line with what you would expect from a node environment.